# When to use .NET TPL vs a simple .NET Thread Pool?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have a windows service I am designing that's going to query a database table to get a list of xml documents to be processed.  I could get 1 document, I could get 100's.  I was originally going to just put each request into a .NET thread pool for processing, but I was wondering if there is a model or example out there of using the .NET TPL for this.  Is it even worth using TPL for such a simple model?

Comment: TPL is intended to largely replace the thread pool. Generally, when unsure, use TPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's little reason to use the thread pool directly nowadays. The basic approach would probably be to use asynchronous I/O to execute the DB request (no threads), and then continue the work on the default (thread pool) task scheduler. If you need to parallelize the processing (and it's actually doable, so you probably want to avoid shared mutable state), you can simply use `Parallel.ForEach` etc.

Of course, if most of the work is done by the DB rather than the client application, you'll be able to do the whole thing with just asynchronous I/O.